# Run ansible task on EC2 instanse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want connect to EC2 instance and run the task in playbook

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: 'all'
  remote_user: 'ubuntu'

  vars:
    ruby_version: '2.2.4'
    user: 'deploy'
    home: '/home/{{ user }}'
    rbenv_root: '{{ home }}/.rbenv'
    name: 'app'
    application: '{{ home }}/applications/{{ name }}'

  tasks:
    - name: 'apt | install dependencies'
      action: 'apt pkg={{ item }}'
      with_items:
        - 'build-essential'
        - 'libssl-dev'
        - 'libyaml-dev'
        - 'libreadline6-dev'
        - 'zlib1g-dev'
        - 'libcurl4-openssl-dev'
        - 'git'
        - 'nginx'
        - 'postgresql'
        - 'postgresql-contrib'
        - 'libpq-dev'
        - 'imagemagick'
        - 'libmagickwand-dev'
        - 'htop'
```

run the command:

```
ansible-playbook -i11.111.1.111, playbook.yml
```

and got this:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [11.111.1.111]

TASK: [apt | install dependencies] ********************************************
failed: [11.111.1.111] => (item=build-essential,libssl-dev,libyaml-dev,libreadline6-dev,zlib1g-dev,libcurl4-openssl-dev,git,nginx,postgresql,postgresql-contrib,libpq-dev,imagemagick,libmagickwand-dev,htop) => {"failed": true, "item": "build-essential,libssl-dev,libyaml-dev,libreadline6-dev,zlib1g-dev,libcurl4-openssl-dev,git,nginx,postgresql,postgresql-contrib,libpq-dev,imagemagick,libmagickwand-dev,htop"}
stderr: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I think I need to specify **AWS_ACCESS_KEY** and **AWS_SECRET_KEY**, but I can't find how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the error message `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?` it means you need run the ansible playbook with root.

could you try with sudo to yes?

```
- hosts: 'all'
  remote_user: 'ubuntu'
  sudo: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, because `sudo: yes` will deprecate soon.

```
---
- hosts: 'all'
  remote_user: 'ubuntu'
  become: yes
```